# Need clarification RouterModule.forRoot([ ABOUT_ROUTE ], { useHash: true })

Tags: router, angular4-router

Kindly explain `useHash: true` method in angular 2 route method.

**My Questions:**

1. what is the purpose we using it.
2. why the value is "true" why not "false" ?
3. if the value is false, what could be happen ?

```
RouterModule.forRoot([ ABOUT_ROUTE ], { useHash: true })
```

Comment: Did you find exact answer to this question. If yes, Please post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, angular uses `HTML5` location-based routing, which may cause you problems in some environments. In the shake of simplicity, we usually prefer hash-based routing which regularly works in every environment. You can have a look at [this post](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-2-routing-navigation) for angular 2 routing